# EF save method that has three conditions

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created this save method that has two conditions. One condition is checking if `coordinatorsId` is not `0` and another one is checking if `Subject` is not empty string. Is there a better way to do the two conditions?

I have come up with the below for the SaveRequest entity. I am looking for advice on ways to improve this. I am using EntityFramework version=6.4.4

```
public ResultStatus SaveRequest(List<int> RequestIds,int DictionaryId, string Subject, int coordinatorsId)
{
    ResultStatus resultStatus = new ResultStatus();
    using (var db = new Entities())
    {
        using (DbContextTransaction dbTran = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {

                foreach (var RequestId in RequestIds)
                {
                    var efRequest = db.Requests.Where(x => x.RequestId == RequestId).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (DictionaryId != 0)
                    {
                        efRequest.DictionaryId= DictionaryId;
                    }
                    if (Subject != ""){
                        efRequest.Subject = Subject;
                    }
                    if (coordinatorsId != 0)
                    {
                        efRequest.coordinatorsId = coordinatorsId ;
                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                dbTran.Commit();

                resultStatus.ResultCode = Convert.ToInt32(Enums.Result.Code.Success);
                resultStatus.Message = "Successfully Saved.";
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                resultStatus.ResultCode = Convert.ToInt32(Enums.Result.Code.Error);
                resultStatus.Message = ex.ToString();
                dbTran.Rollback();
            }
        }
        return resultStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: `RequestIds` and `DictionaryId` parameters never used. What is `SubmissionIds`? `SubmissionId` never used. What is `RequestId` and `efSubmissionRequest`? / Please review your code and correct the typos! I think you have a lot of them.

Comment: Which version of EF are you using? Look at [ExecuteUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete).

Comment: Sorry about that I updated by question.

Comment: what does `coordinatorsId` do? because it seems it's overwriting `efRequest.Title = Subject`. and where `ItemDictionaryId` variable came from ? is it a global property? and what does `DictionaryId` do ? clearly we need more explanation on the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with proper names. Parameters and local variables must have `camelCase` style, properties must have `PascalCase`.

When working with a database, the most important thing is to reduce the number of queries to it.
Therefore, it may make sense to do some checks at the beginning of the method:

```
if (requestIds.Count == 0)
    return resultStatus;

if (dictionaryId == 0 && subject == "" && coordinatorsId == 0)
    return resultStatus;
```

You receive one value from the database in a loop. This is very inefficient.
It is much more profitable to get a set of values at once with one query.

```
var requests = db.Requests.Where(x => requestIds.Contains(x.RequestId)).ToList();

foreach (var request in requests)
{
    if (dictionaryId != 0)
        request.DictionaryId = dictionaryId;

    if (subject != "")
        request.Subject = subject;

    if (coordinatorsId != 0)
        request.CoordinatorsId = coordinatorsId;
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

For string checks, instead of `Subject != ""`, it's more robust to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Subject)` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Subject)` as they cover more cases `(null, empty, or whitespace strings)`.

Your method fetches each `Request` individually within a loop, which can be inefficient if there are many `RequestIds`. You might consider fetching all relevant `Requests` in one query before the loop:

`var efRequests = db.Requests.Where(x => RequestIds.Contains(x.RequestId)).ToList();`

Iterate over `efRequests` to update their properties to reduce the number of database roundtrips.